# can you override loop names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

If python is it possible to change the name of a loop,
eg: `w = while` does not work.
I know it is possible to change the name of print with `p = print`
just wanted to know if you could do this with loops in any way.

Comment: `while` is not a function, but a keyword. You can create references to functions like `p = print` but can't do the same with keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `while` is a keyword, not a name.